# Rotating and scaling a script

Tags: html, css, canvas, p5.js

I have a simple animation written in JavaScript using the p5.js library. I normally place scripts like these on the web using `<script></script>`, and place my canvas in the back using the CSS rules `vertical-align: top; z-index: -1` the canvas of my animations normally scale dynamically, so no need for complicated CSS.

If if have a canvas with a fixed width and height (e.g. 600 x 400), is it possible to apply CSS 2D transforms like `transform: translate(50px, 100px); transform: rotate(50px, 100px);` to the entire canvas? And as a follow up question, how would I point my CSS at the script? Could I give the script it's own class? Or would I have to place the script inside a ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply CSS and 2d transforms on a fixed size canvas element.

```css
canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: black;
  transform: translate(50px, 100px); transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Re: styling a script - you don't style the `script` element itself, as that never displays in the browser. What you would do is style any elements that the `script` creates. So say the `script` creates a `<div class="createdByJS">hello world</div>` to the page, you would then style it via `.createdByJs { color: red; }`.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification. Note my use of the p5.js library, would elements like rect() or ellipse(), rotate and scale with the canvas even if they've been given properties like a width of 20px and a height of 10px?

Comment: @Arkadelic yes you can apply transforms to `rect()` or whatever shapes using p5. You can [go here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/ellipse) and apply them in the dev tools and see for yourself. Re: scaling, if you define a hard width on any HTML element, it doesn't scale with the screen, since the width is a fixed value. Fixed values do not scale automatically. You would either need to use media queries to define breakpoints to resize the canvases as the viewport changes, or use relative units that scale.